# How do you set the value of a newly added ActiveRecord counter cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model object which did not have a counter cache on it before and I added it via a migration. The thing is, I tried and failed to set the starting value of the counter cache based on the number of child objects I already had in the migration. Any attempt to update the cache value did not get written to the database. I even tried to do it from the console but it was never going to happen. Any attempt to write directly to that value on the parent was ignored.

Changing the number of children updated the counter cache (as it should), and removing the ":counter_cache => true" from the child would let me update the value on the parent. But that's cheating. I needed to be able to add the counter cache and then set its starting value to the number of children in the migration so I could then start with correct values for pages which would show it.

What's the correct way to do that so that ActiveRecord doesn't override me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the update_counters method, this blog post has more details:

[josh.the-owens.com add a counter cache to an existing db-table](https://web.archive.org/web/20090928054732/http://josh.the-owens.com/archives/2007/11/03/rails-edge-change-how-to-add-a-counter-cache-to-an-existing-db-table/)

This RailsCasts on the topic is also a good resource:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way is to use `reset_counter_cache`, i.e.:

```
Author.find_each do |author|
  Author.reset_counter_cache(author.id, :books)
end
```

...and that's how you should do it if those tables are of modest size, i. e. <= 1,000,000 rows.

**BUT:** for anything large this will take on the order of days, because it requires two queries for each row, and fully instantiates a model etc.

Here's a way to do it about 5 orders of magnitude faster:

```
Author
  .joins(:books)
  .select("authors.id, authors.books_count, count(books.id) as count")
  .group("authors.id")
  .having("authors.books_count != count(books.id)")
  .pluck(:id, :books_count, "count(books.id)")
  .each_with_index do |(author_id, old_count, fixed_count), index| 
    puts "at index %7i: fixed author id %7i, new books_count %4i,  previous count %4i" % [index, author_id, fixed_count, old_count] if index % 1000 == 0
    Author.update_counters(author_id, books_count: fixed_count - old_count)
  end
```

It's also possible to do it directly in SQL using just a single query, but the above worked well enough for me. Note the somewhat convoluted way it uses the difference of the previous count to the correct one: this is necessary because `update_counters` doesn't allow setting an absolute value, but only to increase/decrease it. The column is otherwise marked readonly.